# How can i have custom access denied page in symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, jms

I am using JMS Security bundle to secure methods and controllers.
When non previleged user access the secure page then i get this error

```
Token does not have the required roles.
```

Is there any way , i can make that custom page and more defined error message

Answer (score 4):

If JMSSecurityExtraBundle answers you with a `403` error [and [it should](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)], you may customize it following [Symfony guidelines](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html).